# What is the Linux command to display how many file names in the directory end in two digits

Tags: shell, files, ls, wildcards

What is the Linux command to display how many file names in the directory end in two digits?
Using `ls` with a command like this :

```
ls -l | wc –l  *[0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: This is one of those times where you should probably be using `find`, not `ls`.

Comment: You might try: `set -- ./*[0-9][0-9] ; echo $#` With that you have a +/- accuracy of 2, I think. You can `[ -e` test `]` positionals for `-e`xistence to make sure they're really files and not just globs to be sure.

Comment: what's the reason `ls -l *[0-9][0-9] | wc -l` wouldn't work?

Comment: @user3678068 A directory named `foo00` containing a bunch of files with no digits in them would be counted. You need at lead `-d`.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash, the following works non-recursively. You can of course put it in a function:

```
shopt -q nullglob || restore=1 && shopt -s nullglob
var=(*[0-9][0-9])
echo ${#var[@]}
[ 1 -eq "$restore" ] && shopt -u nullglob
```

That works even if you have crazy file names. If your file names are not crazy, then you can use that `ls` approach:

```
ls -d1b *[0-9][0-9] | wc -l
```

Note that the flags I used to `ls` are different: `-d` will make list the directory, not its contents (if you had a directory named `something00` for example); `-1` says to use a single column for output; `-b` escapes file names, which will make most crazy file names work.

Both of those will include the directory named `something00` in the count. If you need just files, or recursion, `find` is what you're looking for. This will search the current directory (`.`), recursively, for files (`-type f`) only:

```
find . -type f -name '*[0-9][0-9]' -printf 'f\n' | wc -l
```

Note the use of `-printf`, to print just the letter `f` instead of the file name. You only want to count them, this way its immune to crazy file names.

Answer (score 1):

Without `wc -l` if you want you can use the `tree` command as below.

```
tree -P "*[0-9][0-9]" foldername/
```

**Testing**

Inside one of my folders, I created 3 files that ends with double digits.

First, I issue ls to see all the files.

```
bash-3.2$ ls
1aga21  abcd  kshexp.ksh  new.txt  temp  temp1  temp12  temp2  temp3  temp34
```

Now, I go one folder up to use the tree command.

After that, I issue the `tree` command as below.

```
bash-3.2$ tree -P "*[0-9][0-9]" jun4th/
jun4th/
|-- 1aga21
|-- temp12
`-- temp34

0 directories, 3 files
```

As you can see the final line lists the total files that matches our criteria. The **-P** flag of `tree` command is to specify the patterns.

**EDIT**

As derobert pointed out, if there are directories which ends with 2 numbers and which in turn contains multiple files that ends with 2 numbers the tree command would produce all the files and result in a more noisy output. We can prevent this by tweaking our original command to something like below.

```
tree -P "*[0-9][0-9]" -L 1 jun4th/
```

Notice the flag `-L 1` which means to look for files only in one sublevel below the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a portable way to do the `find` thing:

```
find ././ ! -type d -name '*[0-9][0-9]' | grep -c '^\./\./'
```

And the shell function:

```
set -- ./*[0-9][0-9]
for f do
    [ -e "$f" ] && echo
done | wc -l
```

To recursively and portably count files with `ls` and match only 2-digits exactly at the end of a filename do:

```
ls ./ -aR1iqp |
grep -c '^ *[0-9].*[^0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
```

To search only the current directory do this instead:

```
ls ./.* ./* -ad1iqp |
grep -c '^ *[0-9].*[^0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind Perl:

```
perl -E '@a=<*[0-9][0-9]>;say scalar @a'
```

Note that this (as all other solutions presented so far), assumes that you want to count files whose names end in two *or more* digits. The file `foo123` will be counted as well.

If that's not what you want, the following Perl will print a count of all *files* (as opposed to files and directories) whose name ends in exactly two digits:

```
perl -E 'say scalar grep { -f && /[^0-9][0-9]{2}\z/ } <*>'
```

Comment: good point about the two digits thing. fixed mine. thank you.