# How do I find a file whose name has five digits, in a row, somewhere in the file name?

Tags: linux, command-line, filenames

Normally, I would ask a professor or classmate this, but as it's a Saturday and everyone is gone.  I have to find a file in a directory that has five digits in a row somewhere in the file name.  They don't have to be ascending or descending digits.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134684/what-is-the-linux-command-to-display-how-many-file-names-in-the-directory-end-in

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234201/regex-file-name-with-multiple-digits

Comment: This command line should do it. `find . -name "*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*"`. It can probably be simplified. If there must be exactly 5 digits, that expression will be more complicated.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414226/117549

Comment: If you want to search subdirectories as well: `find -E directory/  -regex '.*[0-9]{5,}.*'`

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Wildcards (or globs) can accomplish this, with a numeric range:

```
ls -d /path/to/directory/*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*
```

This tells the shell to look in /path/to/directory for filenames that start with:

- `*` -- anything (or nothing)
- `[0-9]` -- a digit
- (four more digits)
- `*` -- and ending in anything (or nothing)

That list of filenames is then passed to `ls` to list them.

More expansively, bash also allows character *classes* as wildcards, so if you have numbers in your language that aren't covered by [0-9], you could use:

```
ls -d *[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*
```

Answer (score -1):

I have achieved by below method and i worked fine

```
find . -maxdepth 1  -type f| sed "s/\.\///g"| awk -F "." '{print $1}'|sed '/^$/d'| awk '/[0-9]/{print $0}'| awk '{print $1,gsub("[0-9]",$1)}'| awk '$2 == 5 {print $1}'
```